# Binary operations clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm currently learning about binary operations. To my understanding a binary operation is a type of function which takes two elements from a given set A and then proceeds to give an element from a set B.

The first problem I encounter is one regarding definitions, two textbooks specify that a binary operation $*$ on a set $S$ is a function of the type:
$$\ast : S \times S \to S$$

And then other textbook says a binary operation $*$ on a set $S$ is of the type:

$$\ast : S \times S \to R$$

To my knowledge, this subtle change in the codomain may be quite important, since the first one implies a "closure" of said operation in S (by again, definitions provided by some textbooks) and the second one not (or at least, this is what I consider since the textbook does not clarify this case).

If this was not enough, after i'm presented with this idea of "closure" **i'm told that if the range of an operation is a subset of a set S, then this set S is closed under said operation.** After some thought I realized that

$$+: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$$

is a closed binary operation, since the range of said operation is a subset of Z. But this is not in the form I was told early all closed binary operations are ($S \times S \to S$).

My first question is: What is the correct way to clearly define a binary operation ?
My second one: What is going on with the definition of closure considering the case $+: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ not in the form $S \times S \to S$?

Note: I'm a new learner about these topics so I apologize for any mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: Which textbooks are these? The first one, to my knowledge, defines a binary operation on S correctly, however the author of the second one might have a particular motivation to define it like they did. What is R in the second definition, is it an arbitrary set or possibly a subset of S?

Comment: The first definition is given by two books, one old algebra book in spanish just named "Algebra" which is out of print and "Mathematical Proofs" by Chartrand, Polimeni and Zheng.
The second definition is given by Grimaldi's Discrete Mathematics book (Fifth Edition) and it doesn't specify if R is a subset of S or not.

Answer (score 2):

You happen to have looked at textbooks that provide different definitions of "binary operation". That's fine, as long as each consistently uses its definition. You can't say one is right and the other is wrong.

That said, the most common one is that a binary operation "on $S$" is a function  $S \times S \to S$. Then closure is an adjective applied to subsets of $S$. For example, the set of natural numbers thought of as a subset of the integers is closed under the binary operation addition, but not under subtraction.

When a subset $T \subset S$ is closed under a binary operation on $S$ then restricting that operation to $T \times T$ gives you a binary operation on $T$.